# What's the function for this operator in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

all,

The `numpy` code:

```
data[...]
```

What's the function for this operator [...]?
(data is a `numpy` nd-array)

I've tried on searching on google, but couldn't find any usage or meaning of this operator.

THX!

Comment: Where did you get this line from? My guess is that it's a placeholder for an array without being literal Python code.

Comment: That's an `ellipsis`, as documented https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Comment: You might get a better answer if you show some of the code where this occurs.  For example is in an assignment?  What is the shape of `data`?

Comment: `ellipsis` is a defined constant: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are asking about element wise selection but here is the syntax for that.

```
x = np.arange(10) 
x[2]
2
```

If I've misinterpreted, perhaps explain what the three dots are supposed to represent.

You may be asking for the closest function to the element wise search, in which case you should look at the take() function.